# Windows Form C# Application throws Could not load File or Assembly 'Mimekit' when run on different machine

Tags: c#, package, nuget, mimekit

My mail-provider has made an update, which generated some problems using Dot.Net Mail in an older Windows Form C# solution. I found, that it is recommended to use MailKit/Mimekit instead of Dot.Net mail. So I decided also to upgrade to newer Visual Studio 2019, where I can use NuGet packages.

I installed Visual Studio 2019, installed MailKit using Manage NuGet Packages (Browse, Right Click, Install) and made a simple test-program in C# (Windows Form Solution) where I send an Email with some attachments.

The solution works 100 % - as long as I execute the solution (both debug and Release builds on the PC where the program is build.

**When I copy the Release version (exe-file) to a similar PC (Win 10, DotNet 4.8) I get the following error: *Could not load File or Assembly 'Mimekit, Version 2.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=bede1c8a46c66814' or one of its dependencies.***
The same happens if I transfer the exe-file to a Win 7 - PC.

I have

- Checked that both MailKit an MimeKit is listed in the Solutions References
- Tried to uninstall and reinstall both MailKit and MimeKit (version 2.10.0)
- Tried to upgrade MimeKit to version 2.10.1

It is my first solution in Visual Studio 2019 - as well as my first use of a NuGet Package.
I expected that the built Release Version could be transferred to another PC as a file copy, but something seems to be missing.

I have no clue what to do !?

Comment: .net core installs with visual studio 2019, check that you are using .NET framework and not .net core for your mail application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jada_DK, copying executable alone doesn't make the dependencies available on other PC. You'll need to distribute the application through publish wizard or create an installer. Kindly refer the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/). Alternatively, if it's a quick sample application you don't intend to distribute, you can copy the entire bin/debug or bin/release folder to another machine and run the application.